# How do I find an image on a page with Cucumber / Capybara in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, paperclip

I am using Cucumber / Capybara with Rails 3 and am trying to validate the existence of an image after upload. I'm not sure how to check the url of the image to validate it.

I have the following scenario:

```
Scenario: Create new listing
    Given I am on the new listing page
    When I fill in "listing_name" with "Amy Johnson Photography"
    And I attach the file "features/support/test_image.jpg" to "listing_images_attributes_0_photo" 

    And I press "Create"
    Then I should see "Amy Johnson Photography"
    And I should see the image "test_image.jpg"
```

Everything passes except the last step.

I've tried this for my step definition, which works great if it's text on the page, but doesn't for an image url:

```
Then /^I should see the image "(.+)"$/ do |image|
  if page.respond_to? :should
      page.should have_content(image)
    else
      assert page.has_content?(image)
    end
end
```

Then I've also tried something like this step definition instead:

```
Then /^I should see the image "(.+)"$/ do |image|
    html = Nokogiri::HTML(response.body)
    tags = html.xpath('//img[@src="/public/images/foo.png"]')
    # tags.length.should eql(num_of_images)
end
```

which causes the following error:

```
And I should see the image "test_image.jpg"                                                    # features/step_definitions/listing_steps.rb:41
      undefined method `body' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
      ./features/step_definitions/listing_steps.rb:42:in `/^I should see the image "(.+)"$/'
      features/manage_listings.feature:24:in `And I should see the image "test_image.jpg"'
```

I'm assuming you need a nokogiri step to find this properly. Or if there's a better way, I'm open to suggestions. How can I validate that the image I just uploaded is on the page? Thanks.

Comment: In your step definition you are getting a common capybara error. Try using 'page.body' instead of 'response.body' if I remember correctly.

Comment: I don't know if you can use a regex in xpath, but if you have access to your Listing instance, you could just use a string interpolation "//img[@src='/public/images/#{@listing_id}/foo.png']"

Comment: This page contains a good CSS3 selector reference which will help you: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/css3attributeselectors

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The solution with Nokogiri should work fine. The only problem is that the Cabybara API is different to Webrat, so instead of `response.body`, you must use `page.body`.

But theres an even better way to test for the image with Cabybara :

```
Then /^I should see the image "(.+)"$/ do |image|
    page.should have_xpath("//img[@src=\"/public/images/#{image}\"]")
end
```

Comment: Thanks. That works great. One more thing. My folder names are variable based on the listing_id. How can I use a regex here that searches by only the image name (not the whole url)?

Comment: XPath supports wildcards, so off the top of my head, I imagine you could write something like this: `page.should have_xpath("//img[@src=\"/*/*/#{image}\"]")`

Comment: I can't seem to figure how to get this to work with URLs generated by Dragonfly. They look like this: `/media/BAh_some_long_string_AwIw/12_11_52_810_5x5.jpg?s=7e360000`, where `5x5.jpg` is my file name. I've tried something like: `//img[@src="/media/*/*#{image}?s=*"]` but it doesn't work. Got any tips?

Comment: @Ramon, in case you haven't found a solution yet, here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331231/how-do-i-find-an-image-generated-by-dragonfly-with-cucumber-capybara

Comment: I haven't been able to get the regex working in an image source. If anyone knows a way please add it here. Cheers.

Comment: `page.should have_xpath("//img[contains(@src,'#{image}')]")`
worked for me in order to only match part of the IMG url.

Answer (score 13):

Hi I'm not good with XPATH but with CSS you can try :

```
  if page.respond_to? :should
    page.should have_selector("img[src$='#{imagename}']")
  else
    assert page.has_selector?("img[src$='#{imagename}']")
  end
```

wish helps !
jramby

Comment: This works too: `page.should have_css("img[src$='#{imagename}']")`

Answer (score 6):

You can test it in this way, and also not depending on the path:

```
Then /^I should see the image "(.+)"$/ do |image|
    page.should have_xpath("//img[contains(@src, \"#{image}\")]")
end
```

Comment: This is what is used for images that are saved in dynamic paths such as Paperclip attachments.

Answer (score 6):

> page.should

is now deprecated. Use instead

> expect(page).to

Full example :

```
Then /^I should see the image "(.+)"$/ do |image|
    expect(page).to have_xpath("//img[contains(@src, \"#{image}\")]")
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Does this work?

```
page.should have_xpath('//img[@src="/public/images/foo.png"]')
```

Comment: Thanks. That works great. One more thing. My folder names are variable based on the listing_id. How can I use a regex here that searches by only the image name (not the whole url)?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of images that you would like to test you could create a has_image? matcher for Capybara.

It is easy and this post explains it step-by-step: [Adding a has_image? Matcher to Capybara](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/27/adding-a-has_image-matcher-to-capybara/)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, but these xpath tests won't deal with the fact that...

```
/public/images/foo.jpg
public/images/foo.jpg
http://mydomain.com/public/images/foo.jpg
```

...are all the same valid link to the image.

Answer (score -1):

this syntax worked for me and is more readable.

> page.should have_css("img", :src => "/public/images/foo.png")