# How do I find an image generated by Dragonfly with Cucumber/Capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara, image-upload, dragonfly-gem

In the comments to the solution for [How do I find an image on a page with Cucumber/Capybara](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812606/how-do-i-find-an-image-on-a-page-with-cucumber-capybara-in-rails-3), somebody asked:

> I can't seem to figure how to get this
>   to work with URLs generated by
>   Dragonfly. They look like this:
>   /media/BAh_some_long_string_AwIw/12_11_52_810_5x5.jpg?s=7e360000, where 5x5.jpg is my file name. I've
>   tried something like:
>   //img[@src="/media/*/*#{image}?s=*"]
>   but it doesn't work. Got any tips? – [Ramon Tayag](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61018/ramon-tayag) Feb 25 at 4:18

I have a similar problem, only worse - in my case, the generated image paths don't even include a (jpg|png|gif) file name, they only have these really long ids:

```
<img src="/media/BAhbB1sHOgZmSSIdNGQ4MTEyOGU3ZjViZmQwZTQ4MDAwMDAyBjoGRVRbCDoGcDoKdGh1bWJJIg0yMDB4MjAwIwY7BlQ" />
```

(Using dragonfly with mongo/gridfs)

These paths get rendered alright, but I can't figure out how to find them in a Cucumber/Capybara step :P

Any ideas? I looked at the [Dragonfly's features](https://github.com/markevans/dragonfly/tree/master/features), but they only test the rendering of the image itself, without detecting it's existence within an html page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answering my own question, after [talking to Dragonfly's author](https://github.com/markevans/dragonfly/issues/22#comment_899557) (he's working on making this easier):

```
#route
match '/media/:dragonfly/:file_name', :to => Dragonfly[:images]  

#model
class Store
  include MongoMapper::Document
  key :photo_uid, String
  key :photo_name, String
  image_accessor :photo
end

#view
<%= image_tag @store.photo.thumb('274x207#').url(:suffix => "/#{@store.photo_name}") if @store.photo %>

#cucumber
Then I should see the image "my_photo.png"

Then /^I should see the image "(.+)"$/ do |image|  
  page.should have_xpath("//img[contains(@src, \"#{image}\")]")
end
```

The key is adding an [attachment]_name field to the model, which Dragonfly populates automatically, and then passing it on as a suffix to url(). And the routes needs to allow for a :file_name param besides the generated dragonfly identifier.