# How to test if a partial is rendering an image in erb, rspec, and capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I'm getting started with rspec, capybara, etc, and I want to do some test driven development in Rails.

The specification I'm working with has very precise definitions for the appearance of the headers and the footers, and I figure that these are a good place to start learning.

For the footer, I want to have the following rule:

If the user is logged in, then the header contains just a logo image.  The logo image should be a link to the user's landing page, which is determined by the rights the user has.  If the user is not logged in, then the image is not a link, and four other links should appear in the footer as well, in a table.

Coding this is actually fairly straightfoward in erb, but I'm trying to Do The Right Thing, and make a series of tests here.  My problems is that I can't seem to be able to test whether or not an image is shown on the screen.  I've read the rspec book, but I don't see where it says something like 'shows this image found in the assets directory.'

So my setup is, in the views/layouts directory,
_header.html.erb
_footer.html.erb
_shim.html.erb
application.html.erb

I would think that I could test the footer partial directly, using something like:

```
require "spec_helper"

describe "rendering views/layouts/_footer.html.erb" do
  #from https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-8/docs/view-specs/view-spec
  it "shows the logo" do
    render :template => "layouts/_footer.html.erb"
    rendered.should =~ "/images/mainlogo.png"
  end

describe "rendering views/layouts/_footer.html.erb as admin" do
  before do
    FactoryGirl.create(:admin_user)
  end 
  it "links to landing from the logo"
    render :template => "layouts/_footer.html.erb"
    rendered.should contain("link/to/admin/landing")
  end
end
#repeat landing tests for various user types
```

And then, in other pages, I can simply test for the presence of the footer itself using something like

```
  it should contain("footer")
```

My problem is, I can't even get off the ground to check to see if the image has been shown, much less if the image matches the right one in the assets directory.  What should I be doing here?

The above code for testing the presence of the image (just the first describe/it block, not the stuff with the 'as admin' or the 'should contain') gives me the following warning and error:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Passing a template handler in the template name is deprecated.

TypeError:
   type mismatch: String given
```

The first is probably due to me using syntax I don't understand, but the second seems to suggest that the comparison is with strings rather than assets.  What's the syntax to compare images?  Is there one?

Comment: After some more searching, I found that this is a possible duplicate of [How do I find an image on a page with Cucumber / Capybara in Rails 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812606/how-do-i-find-an-image-on-a-page-with-cucumber-capybara-in-rails-3)

Comment: Does that test whether the image was actually *rendered* or just present in the html? (perhaps that is a silly question, but I mean to say is whether there is an image file at the image location)

Comment: I'd rather the first, but honestly, at this point, I'll take either.  This kind of "Guess the magic word I'm thinking of!  Go on, guess!" style of development is extremely frustrating.

Answer (score 3):

Your type mismatch error is because you're passing a string to `=~` which is a regular expression matcher. You can either change the string to a regular expression, or use the `include` instead. I'd go with `include` just because it's more readable:

```
rendered.should include("/images/mainlogo.png")
```

To get rid of the deprecation warning, just remove the `.erb` from the template name:

```
render :template => "layouts/_footer.html"
```